# 502 bad gateway nginx/1.20.2, laravel 8, php8.1

Tags: nginx

i've been pulling my hair out trying to launch a laravel 8 app on Ubuntu.
I keep getting a 502 Bad Gateway error. Tried changing config files, updating php8.1-fpm.sock, etc. Nothing seems to be working. Can you guys please help?

Thanks!

```
server {
        listen 80;
        listen [::]:80;


        root /var/www/html/appName/public;

        # Add index.php to the list if you are using PHP
        index index.php index.html index.htm index.nginx-debian.html;

        server_name appName.com www.appName.com;

        location / {
                # First attempt to serve request as file, then
                # as directory, then fall back to displaying a 404.
                try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php?$query_string;
        }

        # pass PHP scripts to FastCGI server

        location ~ \.php$ {
                        fastcgi_split_path_info ^(.+\.php)(/.+)$;
                        fastcgi_pass unix:/var/run/php/php8.1-fpm.sock;
                        fastcgi_index index.php;
                        include fastcgi_params;
                        fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;


                        fastcgi_intercept_errors off;
                        fastcgi_buffer_size 16k;
                        fastcgi_buffers 4 16k;
                        fastcgi_connect_timeout 300;
                        fastcgi_send_timeout 300;
                        fastcgi_read_timeout 300;


        }

        # deny access to .htaccess files, if Apache's document root
        # concurs with nginx's one
        #
        location ~ /\.ht {
                deny all;
```

Answer (score 0):

I found the answers poking around. I needed to edit /etc/php-fpm.d/www.conf . and uncomment “listen.mode = 0666”

then afterwards, sudo service php8.1-fpm restart

These sites helped me found the error logs needed to solve the problem.

https://www.datadoghq.com/blog/nginx-502-bad-gateway-errors-php-fpm/#php-fpm-isnt-running

https://bobcares.com/blog/php-fpm-sock-failed-13-permission-denied/